# Swift not finding the correct type

Tags: swift, generics, hamcrest

I am trying to use [SwiftHamcrest](https://github.com/nschum/SwiftHamcrest)

I have a function

```
func equalToArray<T, S>(_ vector:Array<S>) -> Matcher<T> {
  let v: Matcher<T> = Hamcrest.hasCount(16)
  return v
}
```

This gives an error

```
Error:(16, 31) 'hasCount' produces 'Matcher<T>', not the expected contextual result type 'Matcher<T>'
```

SwiftHamcrest has two hasCount functions

```
public func hasCount<T: Collection>(_ matcher: Matcher<T.IndexDistance>) -> Matcher<T> 
public func hasCount<T: Collection>(_ expectedCount: T.IndexDistance) -> Matcher<T>
```

Why is my code complaining isn't it returning the same type that is needed.

As a note and possibly a different question I had to add the Hamcrest. before the hasCount method call as otherwise it tried to match to the first function

What am I missing with types?

Comment: Looks like you want to return a `Matcher<[S]>` rather than a `Matcher<T>` (and then just drop the generic placeholder `T`). Although I'm not sure what the `vector` parameter is for.

Comment: @Hamish - this is a cut down case where I want other matchers - so yes the parameter is not required in this example fuller example is func equalToArray<T: Collection, S>(_ vector:Array<S>) -> Matcher<T> {

 let v: Matcher<T> = Hamcrest.hasCount(vector.count)
 return v
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `equalToArray<T, S>` does not know that `T` is a collection, so the result from the generic `hasCount(...)` methods above will not be assignable to `v` in your method (since these results returns `Matcher<T>` instances constrained to `T`:s that are `Collection`:s). I.e., `v` is of a type `Matcher<T>` for a non-constrained `T`, meaning, in the eyes of the compiler, there is e.g. no `T.IndexDistance` for the `T` of `v`:s type.

If you add a `Collection` type constraint to the `T` of your method, the assignment from `hasCount(...)` result to `v` should compile:

```
func equalToArray<T: Collection, S>(_ vector: Array<S>) -> Matcher<T> {
    let v: Matcher<T> = Hamcrest.hasCount(16)
    return v
}
```

In a perfect world, the compiler could've given us a more telling error message, say along the lines of

> Error:(16, 31) '`hasCount`' produces '`Matcher<T>`' where '`T: Collection`',
>   not the expected contextual result type '`Matcher<T>`'

---

Now, I don't know what you're intending to test here, but as @Hamish points out, you might actually want to return a `Matcher<[S]>` and drop the `T` placeholder. E.g. using the `count` property of the supplied `vector` parameter as argument to `hasCount(...)`?

```
func equalToArray<S>(_ vector: Array<S>) -> Matcher<[S]> {
    return hasCount(vector.count)
}
```

Not having used Hamcrest myself, I might be mistaken, but based on a quick skim over the SwiftHamcrest docs, I believe `equalToArray(_:)` defined as above would construct a matcher for "vector equality" (w.r.t. semantics of the function name) based only on the count of two vectors, in which case the following assert would be a success

```
let arr1 = ["foo", "bar"]
let arr2 = ["bar", "baz"]

assertThat(arr1, equalToArray(arr2)) // success! ...
```

But this is just a byline, as you haven't shown us the context where you intend to apply your `equalToArray(_:)` method/matcher; maybe you're only showing us a minimal example, whereas the actual body of you custom matcher is more true to the method's name.

Comment: yes I know this is not a good comparison of vectors - I just cut the example down to one error in the hope that understanding this would help me in the rest - but it doesn't :(

Comment: In general I was trying to pass an array to a function taking T... - unfortunately not possible https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-128 so the first part of your answer fixes my question but the general problem is not fixable - I need to rewrite the external library to take arrays :(

Comment: @Mark ah yes, that is a known limitation, but for many use cases you can work around it by providing an overload taking a `[T]` argument instead of `T...` (this would be the overload where you have the implementation logic), and letting the `T...` method simply call the latter overload. Remember that a variadic parameter is just an array in the body of the function to which it is supplied. See e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/5dcb0764f849e6d454cd57ff05109582) for an example. Possible such a workaround can be useful in your case.

Comment: @dn yes but unfortunately the library has made private the lower level code  so I can't override it. In this case there is another library doing similar things that has exposed calls with arrays

Comment: @Mark I see, that's too bad :/